# Comparing Proportions of Time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, independence, proportion

If we imagine that someone is interested in whether employees in certain industries sustain workplace injuries disproportionately, and they have data like the following...

| Industry | # Employees w/ Injuries | # Employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carpentry | 100 | 1000 |
| Shipping | 25 | 500 |
| Welding | 10 | 250 |

... then I believe they can use a chi-square proportions test or similar to test whether the proportions implied by the middle column are different from the proportions implied by the rightmost column.

However, if the data of interest are more like the following...

| Industry | Days of Work Missed Due to Injury | Total Days on Payroll |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carpentry | 200 | 300,000 |
| Shipping | 75 | 150,000 |
| Welding | 100 | 75,000 |

...then a chi-square proportions test seems inappropriate since many of the "days" are accounted for by the same individuals and thus aren't really independent observations.

**Is there a sensible test to compare the proportions implied by the middle and rightmost columns of the second table?**

Happy to provide any further info that would be helpful, and my apologies if I've overlooked something basic in setting this up.

Comment: 'Round' numbers throughout suggest that these are fictitious data for a homework problem. I will show results for one of the two parts in R and let you show expected counts and computations of chi-squared statistics on your own. // This question needs a `self-study` tag.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for writing! Not a homework problem (I'm not a student), but I can't share the actual data, so these are fictitious. Hope that's all right.

Comment: As long as the fictitious rounded numbers are good approximations of the actual counts, results should be similar. Of course the method is the same.

Answer (score 7):

I put your counts into a table (please proofread).

```
Inj = c(100, 25, 10)
Tot = c(1000, 500, 250)
NoI = Tot - Inj

TBL = rbind(Inj,NoI)
TBL
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
Inj  100   25   10
NoI  900  475  240
```

Then you can do a chi-squared test in R. (By default, the Yates correction is used; it make little difference here.)

```
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 17.358, df = 2, p-value = 0.0001702
```

The null hypothesis (that proportions are homogeneous across industries, is
strongly rejected with P-value about 0.0002.

In R, an alternative test of proportions, compares $\hat p_C = .10, \hat p_S = .05, \hat p - 0.04,$ finding that there are significant differences among
population. In R, this test is
equivalent to the chi-squared test. [In various statistical software programs you may find variations of this test--depending on rounding conventions, and on how the standard error of the test statistic is computed.]

```
prop.test(Inj, Tot)

        3-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  Inj out of Tot
X-squared = 17.358, df = 2, p-value = 0.0001702
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 
  0.10   0.05   0.04
```

Neither test resolves where the significant differences may lie. You
would have to do *ad hoc* tests (using significance levels suggested
by Bonferroni's method of guarding against false discovery from
repeated analyses of the same data). For example, the chi-squared
test to compare Shipping and Welding, goes as follows, finding a significant
difference. I will leave it to you to run `chisq.test` on other sub-matrices
of `TBL`.

```
chisq.test(TBL[,c(2.3)])$p.val
[1] 4.49277e-90
```

---

*Note:* Similarly, I also get highly significant results for data on days missed due to
injuries.

```
DaysS = c(200, 75, 100)
TotD  = c(300000, 150000, 75000)
DaysN =TotD - DaysS
TAB = rbind(DaysS, TotD)
TAB
       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
DaysS 2e+02     75   100
TotD  3e+05 150000 75000
chisq.test(TAB)$p.val
[1] 9.429762e-12
```

This test has to be viewed as a somewhat approximate one
because days are not independent in the same
way that accidents are: one accident can
result in one day out of work or many.

If you want to use 'days off' as a measure
of the seriousness of an accident, then you
might show the number of days off for each
employee accident. *In a separate question,*
you might show such data and get opinions
on which tests to use.

Addendum: Another look at this using `prop.test'

```
DaysS = c(200, 75, 100)
TotD  = c(300000, 150000, 75000)
prop.test(DaysS, TotD)

        3-sample test for equality 
        of proportions without 
        continuity correction

data:  DaysS out of TotD
X-squared = 50.87, df = 2, p-value = 8.991e-12
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
      prop 1       prop 2       prop 3 
0.0006666667 0.0005000000 0.0013333333
```

'Prop 1' of 0.0007 and 'Prop 3' of 0.0013
are different. But they are **not** binomial
proportions of 300,000 or 75,000 **independent** days. Undoubtedly there are
some people who were out for two weeks and
some out for 2 days.

If there is some way
you feel comfortable saying 0.0007 and 0.0013
are meaningfully comparable, then go ahead.
If not, try to make better sense of it.
Are Carpenters prone to minor injuries
that take half as long to recover from as
injuries of Welders. Or are Carpenters
injured less often than Welders?

If the daily outage rate of Carpenters
can be taken as 0.0007 compared to
0.0015 for Welders, then in ten 1000-day
work periods, Carpenters and Welders, may have respective numbers of days out as below, where the Poisson accidents are random within each 1000-day span.

```
rpois(10, .7)
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1
rpois(10, 1.3)
[1] 0 1 3 0 3 0 0 1 2 2
```

Wondering whether that makes sense or seems
right to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I had worried that multiple days coming from each person would pose an independence problem and make the "total days" case require a different test than the "number of people" case. Am I correct in understanding that this isn't actually an issue? Thanks again!

Comment: Just saw your edit -- thank you for the clarification. Maybe my question wasn't framed well enough, but that's really what I'm wondering about. Assuming a case like this one, where lengths of individual injuries / tenures on payroll aren't known, but the group totals are, is there an appropriate way to compare the proportions? Much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can etic your Question to show how your would propose summarizing data to show days off because of each individual injury.

Comment: That would be interesting, but it's not really what I'm trying to understand at the moment. Is there an appropriate test to use on the data exactly as presented in the second table in the question? If not, that's very helpful to know. Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of tests one could do. But no test is any good unless one has a clear idea what is meant by, say 75 days of work lost out of 150,000. Is that one 'hazard' rating for Shipping? Or does that say something interesting about each of the 150,000 days. Is there a way to relate that to the lives of x nr. of people who work in Shipping? // See Addendum.

Comment: Sure, thanks for asking. Let's say we're interested in studying whether some industries are more dangerous than others, and all we know is total days missed per industry, plus total days on payroll per industry. If all industries had the same days on payroll, we could compare days missed directly, of course. But I think, in a case like this one, we're really interested in whether the allocation of days missed to industries resembles the allocation of days on payroll to industries. If independence were satisfied, the chi-squared you mentioned would be ideal. Does that help? Thanks again!

Comment: Independence would have to be _assumed._ Might be a reasonable  assumption. See speculation in addendum. Then after some thought maybe post the second part anew with your latest ideas so see what others think of your model.